# Uninstall TCP/IPv4 (Server 2016)

Tags: windows-server-2016, nic, ipv4

In Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter there is a properties window for network interfaces, inside that properties window there are several checkboxes that control protocols. (Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) being one of them).

On several of the protocols listed there is an uninstall option. However this uninstall option is grayed out for IPv4. Is there a way to uninstall it?

I have tried to use the command `netsh interface IPv4 uninstall`, and it says the computer must be restarted to complete the action; after a restart the protocol is still present on the stack available for the interface.

Comment: What protocol, pray tell, do you expect the server to communicate on the network with if you remove TCP/IP?

Comment: @joeqwerty, there's no reason you couldn't use IPv6 exclusively, is there?

Comment: turns out I don't know how to check things..

Answer (score 3):

Despite still appearing on the list (and being check-able) IPv4 was uninstalled (with command `netsh interface IPv4 uninstall`).

This is shown by trying to run the command `ping google.com /4` to which Windows responds `IPv4 Protocol is not installed.` Checking does not reinstall the protocol, nor does restarting the server while it's checked. It also grays out the properties button in the properties list.